# How to say that a point should be skipped so that we can move on to a better (or deeper) question?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

My question is in the context of essay writing. My essay will discuss the viewpoints presented by [this video](https://www.facebook.com/bbcnews/videos/326814944647032/) from BBC. In the video, the question "How should we include transgender athletics in sport?" is discussed.

Let me give a brief summary about the video first.

Over all, the video presents the case for and against the rules that allow trans women to compete in female sport subject to the condition that the trans women keep their level of testosterone low for a certain period of time. In the first half of the video, people express a view that this kind of hormone therapy doesn't do enough to eliminate an advantage trans women have because even after the therapy they still have a male body. On average, trans women will be taller, bigger and stronger than their female counterparts.

The part of the video that is particularly relevant to my question is when a medical expert, whose her research plays a role in determining the rules, introduce a new question "Can transgender women and cisgender compete against one another in meaningful competition?" [4:55 in the video]

I want to write a part of essay that conveys a meaning similar to this: "Please don't keep arguing endlessly that trans women have got physical advantages over women in sport... In stead, what we should care is whether or not it is still possible for them to compete in a meaningful way." (By meaningful, I mean that the gap in physical strength between trans women and women is reduced to the point that trans women do not always win.)

Comment: Whoever's chairing the debate in such contexts will often say ***Moving on...*** - and then introduce some new but relevant issue (particularly if the discussion doesn't seem to be getting anywhere). But there are any number of different ways of announcing a shift in the conversational focus, as parodied by *Monty Python's* [***And Now for Something Completely Different***.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_Now_for_Something_Completely_Different)

Answer (score 1):

If you discuss the point about the physical advantages, you could transition into the topic of the meaningful way by saying something like "But enough about...".  You could also say something like "Instead of arguing endlessly about physical attributes, we should..."